# django comment: how to specify the sort direction?

Tags: python, django, sortdirection

I am using comment app in django, but currently the sort direction is by date(from old to new), I want the comments are displayed by date from new to old, how to change it?

Comment: Are you trying to order in a view or on the model as a whole? Is this an app you made yourself or is it third-party?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do:

```
{% get_comment_list for event as comment_list %}
{% for comment in comment_list reversed %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Answer (score 1):

You can use the minus sign to inverse the ordering.

`t = Theme.objects.order_by('-pub_date')`

Avoid using business logic in the templates as much as possible.

[the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)